# UIViewController on bounds changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I need a way to detect when the bounds of a UIViewController have been changed(e.g. when the phone rotates)

For UIView I do it this way:

```
 -(void)setBounds:(CGRect)newBounds
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, please elaborate this.

Comment: Made changes, hope it is more clear.

Comment: Do you only need to know when a rotation has taken place? You could just post to NSNotificationCenter when rotation occurs and listen to a custom message to know when the phone has rotated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method to use is documented in the "Handling View Rotations" section of the UIViewController class reference,

> In iOS 8, all rotation-related methods are deprecated. Instead,
>   rotations are treated as a change in the size of the view controller’s
>   view and are therefore reported using the
>   viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: method. When the
>   interface orientation changes, UIKit calls this method on the window’s
>   root view controller. That view controller then notifies its child
>   view controllers, propagating the message throughout the view
>   controller hierarchy.